# Objective-C How to splice HTML source and set it as a UILabel

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have a URL that I am sending requests through

```
@"http://******.**********.com/?login=%@&password=%@&form.submitted=true",username.text, password.text];
```

Then I use the following code to get the source from that webpage:

```
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSError *err = nil;

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

Now, I want to splice that html so I can get ONLY what is in a tag.

```
<td title="Verified Hours">
      858.97
</td>
```

How can I splice this html source so I can result in just (for example) 858.97?

Comment: You have two choices:  1) Use a regular expression to find that tag.  2) Use an HTML parser to find that tag and get its value

Comment: what regular expression can I use?

Comment: This one is a pretty straightforward "Capture everything between these two things". You can test your regexs at http://www.rubular.com

Comment: Please note apple will reject applications that scrape web pages to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open source Code called DTCoreText 
It can help you change the Html To Navtive View.
...UILabel,UIImageView,UIButton....

you can search in github or https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I solved my problem by using this HTML Parser:

https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser